# Displayed nested HashMaps with a TreeSet to display index of the word in a certain file

Tags: java, file, indexing, hashmap, cpu-word

I want to display ( in JSON format ) a list of words contained in a file, with first key being the word, second key being the file it's from and values are the index of the word when it's found in the file.Only problem is it seems like the new TreeSet has a problem because all my words have the same HashMap<String, TreeSet>. They all have the same nested HashMap but I want every one of them to be individual and independent of course. Would love a little help.
Here is my code:

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>> listStems(Path inputFile) throws 
IOException {
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>> finalString = new HashMap<String, 
    HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>>();
    HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>> mapString = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>();
    int counter=0;
    Stemmer stemmer = new SnowballStemmer(DEFAULT);
    try (BufferedReader br =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(inputFile.toString()), "UTF-8"));) {    
                String line;
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] toStemArray = parse(line);
                    
                    for(int i = 0;i<toStemArray.length;i++) {
                        counter++;
                        if(!finalString.containsKey(toStemArray[i])) {
                            mapString.put(inputFile.toString(), new TreeSet<Integer>());
                            finalString.put(toStemArray[i], mapString);
                            finalString.get(toStemArray[i]).get(inputFile.toString()).add(counter);
                        }
                        else if(finalString.containsKey(toStemArray[i])) {
                            finalString.get(toStemArray[i]).get(inputFile.toString()).add(counter);
                        }
                    }
                }
    }       
    return finalString;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `HashMap<String, TreeSet>` instances are the same because you only create a single instance (`mapString`) at the start of your method, then re-use it.

In your inner `if` statement, you check to see if you've seen the word before, and if you haven't you add an entry to your one single `HashMap<String, TreeSet>` that maps the file name to a new, empty `TreeSet<Integer>`.  That's almost the right pattern--you're detecting a new word and creating a new `TreeSet`, but not creating a new `HashMap<String, TreeSet>`.

If you want to have one `HashMap<String, TreeSet>` per word, you'll need to create a new one every time you see a new word instead of just once.  Move your `new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Integer>>()` to immediate before the `mapString.put` line and you'll *almost* have it working: you'll have one `HashMap<String, TreeSet>` per word but now you're only creating a single `TreeSet`.

Fix that the same way (by making a new `TreeSet` if you haven't seen that file for that word before) and you should be good!

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thank you so much

Comment: I tried implementing the second part, which takes care of what happens if the file the word is coming from is not part of the initial map and on my output file I have only one file per map and it's always the last file used as input. Any way to change that? I'm kinda lost